# locationServicesEnabled == YES, but [[CLLocationMagager alloc] init] returns nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

I'm a bit puzzled. Consider the following code:

```
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
            if(self.locationManager == nil)
            {
                    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            }
            // do something with the location manager...
    }
```

`self.locationManager` is set to 0x0. The conditions for both alternatives are met. I checked this using a breakpoint at `self.locationManager = ...` and the line is called on each start of the app. Most interestingly, a MKMapView in the same view controller is able to show the user's location.

Thanks for any insights,
Chris

Comment: You say "on each start of the app". Would that not be what you'd expect for the object to be nil when your app launches?

Comment: how do you define locationManager property? I also suppose you are importing #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> and adding that framework, right?

Comment: @onnoweb: `self.locationManager` is initialized with nil in the `init` method. Later the above shown code is called by `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @LocoMike: `@property(weak, nonatomic) CLLocationManager* locationManager;` <-- Could that be a problem? I guessed, that the instances of CLLocationManager are managed by the framework, so I decided on a weak ownership relation. And yes and yes to the import and framework questions.

Comment: @LocoMike: Changing the property ownership relation from weak to strong did the trick, thank you. (As I am a new user I may not answer my own question for the next 7 hours...)

Comment: Yeah, so your problem was that you were not retaining the manager. It i like you create memory for it, but immediately after you remove the memory. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the declaration of `locationManager` as

```
    @property(weak, nonatomic) CLLocationManager* locationManager;
```

The framework does not retain each location manager instance, so I should have declared

```
    @property(strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager* locationManager;
```

instead, which works perfectly.

Thanks to LocoMike for pointing me into the right direction.